# Exclusão de itens em List

Tags: c#, linq

Pessoal tenho um:`List<Grupos> lista = new List<Grupos>();`

E tenho esse código

```
var matches = lista.FindAll(x => x.Nome_Grupo.ToLower().Contains(txtFiltro.Text)).ToList();
```

Para filtrar somente palavras do meu **TxtFiltro**, gostaria de filtrar todos os itens que não tenha a palavra que coloquei no **TxtFiltro** e se possível colocar mais de uma palavra.

Exemplo trazer todos os itens que não contenha: abacaxi, morango.

Comment: Você vai colocar todas essas palavras no textbox?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 3):

Para filtrar você pode usar o método [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
var matches = lista.Where(x => !x.Nome_Grupo.ToLower().Contains(txtFiltro.Text)).ToList();
```

Para filtrar mais de um valor você pode utilizar uma `List` e verificar se o valor que está filtrando existe dentro dela.

```
var filtros = new List<string>() {"abacaxi", "morango"};
var matches = lista.Where(x => !filtros.Contains(x.Nome_Grupo.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que eu entendi da pergunta, é isso

```
var matches = lista.Where(x => !x.Nome_Grupo.ToLower().Contains("abacaxi") &&
                               !x.Nome_Grupo.ToLower().Contains("morango")).ToList();
```

Caso precise validar muitos valores, seria melhor colocá-los em uma coleção e depois validar, assim (levando em consideração que todas as palavras estão no textbox, separados por vírgulas - sem espaços).

```
var palavrasFiltro = txtFiltro.Text.ToLower().Split(',');
var matches = lista.Where(x => !palavrasFiltro.Contains(x.Nome_Grupo.ToLower())).ToList();
```

[Veja um exemplo no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hFVgJQ)

Comment: tentei aqui mas não funcionou, usei o segundo exemplo com Split. Testei com 1 palavra e com mais de uma.

Comment: Não funcionou como? O que aconteceu? Estou sem windows pra testar.

Comment: Veja um exemplo funcionando aqui https://dotnetfiddle.net/hFVgJQ

Comment: Testei seu exemplo dotnetfiddle e deu certo, acho que estou com problema ToLower pq tenho palavras que Tem maiúscula e minuscula o ideal era transformar tudo para maiúscula e fazer o filtro, correto? Tem como ignorar o case sensitive?

Comment: Você tem palavras com letras maiúsculas e minúsculas onde? No textbox? Se sim, faça `txtFiltro.Text.ToLower().Split(',');`

Comment: Não sei o que acontece mais aqui na minha aplicação não funciona. Eu tenho uma frase com algumas palavras, "Contains" tinha que funcionar, mas não está obedecendo.

Comment: Mostre o código, jovem. Se você não sabe o que está acontecendo, imagine eu, que nem consigo ver seu código.

Comment: Olha o exemplo com frases.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/aZvenw

Comment: Com frases não vai funcionar mesmo. Veja bem, a palavra `noivas` contém a frase `noivas de plantão`? **Não**, é ao contrário, `noiva` está contida em `noivas de plantão`. Se você tivesse dito que iria trabalhar com frases, mudaria todo o rumo das respostas.

Comment: Entendi, abro outra pergunta então?

Comment: Deve ter uma maneira menor e mais simples de fazer isso, mas assim você consegue o resultado que você quer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6V8zQ4. Não vou colocar esse código na resposta porque não foi isso que você perguntou...