# Como filtrar itens que não contenha palavra em um list?

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

Tenho um: `List<Grupos> lista = new List<Grupos>();`

E tenho esse código

```
var txtFiltro = "noivas,unhas";
var palavrasFiltro = txtFiltro.ToLower().Split(',');
matches = lista.Where(x => !palavrasFiltro.Contains(x.Nome_Grupo.ToLower().ToString())).ToList();
```

Esse código filtra tudo o que for diferente do texto que estou informando, porém só funciona se tiver **uma** palavra, se tiver **frases** não funciona, como poderia fazer a implementação desse filtro?

[Aqui tem um código](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tCXWmy) que o usuário @jbueno me ajudou.

Comment: O que é uma frase pra você? É pra funcionar com frases sim, a busca pelo texto não para em espaços em branco.

Comment: Você quer saber se uma string maior **não** contém as palavras listadas em palavrasFiltro?

Comment: Vamos dizer que em meu List tenho 10 registros dentro desses 10 registros tenho frases ex: "Eu gosto de batata", "Eu gosto de morango", "Eu gosto de laranja". No meu filtro eu quero que meu List filtre tudo o que não contém a palavra "laranja". Desse jeito meu list só teria os registros "Eu gosto de batata", "Eu gosto de morango".

Comment: Mas isto já está fazendo.

Comment: Não está! Não funciona com frases se fosse somente dentro do list a palavra "laranja" funcionaria.

Comment: Mas você acabou de falar no exemplo do comentário que é isto que quer. Vou repetir o que eu perguntei: defina pra você o que é uma frase.

Comment: Pessoal, vou tentar explicar novamente. Tenho um List.
  var lista = new[]
  {
   new{Nome_Grupo = "Noiva de Plantão"},
   new{Nome_Grupo = "Noivas 2016/ 2017 - RJ"},
   new{Nome_Grupo = "Noivas Goianas"},
   new{Nome_Grupo = "DEUS ACIMA DE TUDO"},
   new{Nome_Grupo = "No Colo De Nossa Senhora"}, 
  };
Agora preciso que quando digitar uma palavra ex: "Deus" o List me retorne todos os itens que NÃO contenha a palavra "Deus". Nesse caso Acima me retornaria os itens 1,2,3 e 5. O item 4 Seria o item que o meu filtro tem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O algoritmo apresentado no *link* está errado. Está procurando a frase dentro de palavras, isto não vai funcionar mesmo. Não dá pra procurar uma texto maior dentro de um menor, o maior nunca estará dentro do menor. Se era isto que queria, é matematicamente impossível e não faz o menor sentido.

Se estiver procurando frases mesmo, é só usar a frase. O espaço entre palavras não vai atrapalhar nada.

Se o que quer é usar algumas palavras soltas como filtro, precisa criar um mecanismo mais complexo de filtro. Embora dê para fazer 100% no LINQ eu acho interessante criar um método de extensão que resolva isto (até dá para usar LINQ nele, se desejar). Na verdade nem precisa ser uma método de extensão, mas fica mais conveniente usá-lo.

Este método tem que verificar se cada uma das *strings* usadas no filtro está contida dentro de cada frase.

Tem maneiras mais performáticas de fazer isto, mas é mais complexo, não sei se compensa.

```
public static bool ContainsAny(this string haystack, params string[] needles) {
    foreach (var needle in needles) {
        if (haystack.Contains(needle)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/nhFops). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PUcelA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ContainsAny.cs).

Forma com LINQ:

```
public static bool ContainsAny(this string haystack, params string[] needles) => needles.Any(x => haystack.Contains(x));
```

Na verdade se quiser garantir que seja apenas palavras exatas, a coisa complica. Este exemplo (baseado no anterior aplicado, portando se este não fizer o que deseja, o outro também não o fará) se procurar por "noiva", achará "noivado", mesmo que não queira isto. Esta procura não é por palavras, é por trechos de texto, ela não observa a sintaxe do texto.

Se quiser resolver isto ingenuamente teria que separar a frase em palavras e verificar a igualdade de cada uma.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/99wuLv). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/swSOWW). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/ContainsAnyExt.cs).

Isto não resolve todos os casos. Um *parsing* mais completo é necessário para atender todos casos, aí fica complicado.

Aí deve pensar: se eu quiser "noiva" e "noivas"? Tem que tratar como se fosse duas palavras. O mesmo vale para conjugação de verbo, mudança de gênero, etc.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado bigown!!!

Comment: Seria muito complicado procurar palavra exata? Acabei caindo nesse caso que você me falou do "noiva", achará "noivado",

Comment: Fazer direito é um pouco complicado, fazer mais ou menos é fácil. Vou tentar por um exemplo.

Comment: Beleza vou ficar aguardando, obrigado!

Comment: Só pra explicar: O algoritmo do link só está errado porque é oriundo de uma pergunta pouco clara. Eu digo aqui [neste comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128061/exclus%c3%a3o-de-itens-em-list#comment267114_128064)

Answer (score 3):

Acho que o problema é que você está procurando a string maior dentro da menor, i.e.: você está vendo se o filtro contém a frase e não o contrário.

Sugiro:

```
string[] palavrasFiltro; // mantive array porque é o que você usa...
List<string> lista; // ... mas eu prefiro trabalhar com listas. Suas frases ficam aqui.
List<string> remocao = new List<string>();

foreach (string elemento in lista)
{
    foreach (string filtro in palavrasFiltro)
    {
        if (elemento.Contains(filtro))
        {
            remocao.Add(elemento);
            break;
        }
    }
}

foreach (string s in remocao)
{
    lista.Remove(s);
}
```